# can't insert data in php poo

Tags: php, crud

i'veen following a tutorial about oop php and I was doing the C of the crud, where I have a user with its attributes. When i'm doing the insert into the bd it just save () or {()}, in the example the person uses 
`
 public function save(){

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellidos, email, password,rol,) VALUES('{$this->getNombre()}',
   '{$this->getApellidos()}','{ $this->getEmail()}','{$this->getPassword()}','user')";
   $save = $this->db->query($sql);
   $result=false;
   if($save){
        $result=true;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

`

But when I use it, I get only save {()} on the db. I tried erasing the {} from the getters, and saving the attributes in new variables and  writting it in the query but I can't make it works.
[Here it's my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfB01.png)

And  [the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgMqe.png)

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Lookup complex (curly) syntax.

Comment: use [prepared querys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) no excuse. though your error is saying about dupe keys on a column which your not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid sql injection you should use prepared statements. These come with PDO and are pretty simple to use. Have a look at the following example.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO 
        usuarios 
        (nombre, apellidos, email, password,role) 
    VALUES
        (:nombre, :apellidos, :email, 'user')
";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([
    'nombre' => $this->getNombre(),
    'apellidos' => $this->getApellidos(),
    'email' => $this->getEmail()
]);

return $result;
```

Further more you can wrap the execution of your sql query via PDO in a try/catch block. So if any exception occurs, you can catch it and see, what exactly went wrong.

```
try {
    // execute your logic here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e, $this->db->errorInfo());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Beside that your SQL Syntax got an error. The last comma after `rol`. Further the error message says, that an entry `()` for the key `uq_email` already exists. This kind of exeptions you can catch with the above shown try/catch block.